# Using Javascript to enter values into multiple input fields of a website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pre-face this post by saying I am a complete noob at JavaScript, but I'm willing to learn. I currently work in a job that requires a fair amount of data entry. This data entry is in the form of taking some numbers from excel and putting them into Salesforce apps (think financial forecasting, budgeting etc) Historically, there was a handy little script that would make a box appear allowing us to copy and paste the numbers from excel and populate the individual cells in Salesforce. I'm looking to re-create a similar tool for me and my team.

```
javascript:$e = $('<div id="forecastValuesDiv">
<strong>Forecast Values Entry</strong>
<br /><br />Enter values for forecast units, up to a maximum of 9 columns x 20 rows.<br /><br />
The cursor does not need to be in any field.<br /><br />
<textarea id="forecastValues" rows="15" cols="60"></textarea>
<br /><br /><strong>Detected Values:<strong><br />
<span id="detectedValuesText"></span><br />
<button type="button" id="submitForecastValues">Enter forecast values</button> 
<button type="button" id="closeForecastValues">Close</button>
</div>');
$('body').append($e);
$e.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '150px', right: '10px', 
         width: '400px', height: '400px', backgroundColor: 
         'white', "border": "solid 3px #096", "z-index": 
         '1000', "padding": "5px", "text-align": 
         "center"});
$e.draggable(); 
var inputRows = 0, inputColumns = 0, valueRows = 0, valueColumns = 0; 
$("#editButton").click(function()
{ 
    var dataTableRows = $(".list.dataTable tbody").children(); 
    var dataTableCells = $(dataTableRows[0]).find("input:visible");
    inputRows = dataTableRows.length; 
    inputColumns = dataTableCells.length; 
    updateDetectedInput(); 
}); 
$("#cancelButton, #nextButtonSave, #previousButtonSave").click(function() 
{ 
    inputRows = 0; 
    inputColumns = 0; 
    updateDetectedInput();
}); 
$("#forecastValues").on('input',function(e) 
{ 
    var textAreaValue = $("textarea#forecastValues").val().trim();
    if( textAreaValue.length > 0 ) 
    {
        var rows = textAreaValue.split(/[\r\n]+/g); 
        valueRows = rows.length; 
        if( valueRows > 0 ) 
        {
            valueColumns = rows[0].trim().split(/\s+/g).length;              
        }
        else
        {
            valueColumns = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        valueRows = 0; 
        valueColumns = 0; 
    } 
    updateDetectedInput(); 
}); 
function updateDetectedInput() 
{ 
    $("#detectedValuesText").html("Input boxes: " + inputRows + " rows x " + inputColumns + " columns<br />Values: " + valueRows + " rows x " + valueColumns + " columns<br/>"); 
}; 
$("#submitForecastValues").click(function() 
{
    var dataTableRows = $(".list.dataTable tbody").children();    
    var yearValues = $("textarea#forecastValues").val().trim().split(/[\r\n]+/g); 
    var dataTableRowsLength = dataTableRows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataTableRowsLength; i++) 
    {
        var dataTableCells = $(dataTableRows[i]).find("input:visible"); 
        var monthValues = yearValues[i].trim().split(/\s+/g); 
        var dataTableCellsLength = dataTableCells.length; 
        for(var j = 0; j < dataTableCellsLength ; j++) 
        {
            if(monthValues[j] !== undefined)
            {
                 dataTableCells[j].value = monthValues[j];
            }
        }
    }
}); 
$("#closeForecastValues").click(function()
{
    $e.remove(); 
}); 
updateDetectedInput();
```

This code was for a slightly different app within Salesforce and therefore does not work for what I need it for. Essentially, there are 3 columns of data with varying amounts of rows. Right now, we have to type the data individually from one cell to the next, I'd like to simplify this by creating a script that will allow us to just copy and paste the values from excel, using space as the denominator and enter them into separate cells.

Hope this makes sense!

EDIT: Found another similar tool that we use for another thing that would also potentially do the trick:

```
javascript:input = prompt("Enter values","");var activeElementId = document.activeElement.id;var monthValues = input.split(/(\s+)/);var monthNumber = 1;for(value in monthValues) {var monthElement = activeElementId.replace(/_ctl[0-9]{2}_txtAmount$/gi, "_ctl"+(monthNumber < 10? "0"+monthNumber:monthNumber)+"_txtAmount");document.getElementById(monthElement).value = monthValues[value];monthNumber++;}
```

This creates a pop up box that we paste our numbers in, after we press ok those values are then distributed across the separate input fields. How could I amend this to work for me?

Comment: It would greatly help if you could provide the HTML you're working with as well

Comment: Hi, sorry - I don't know if I've explained myself well enough. I'm not working with any HTML - I'm not designing the page. The page has already been designed, I'm just using it to enter the values into the system as part of my job.

Comment: Yes but you still need to show us the relevant HTML that you're trying to write the code for otherwise we won't know how to write code which will correctly insert data into it in the right places

Comment: There is some HTML hard coded into the script you've shown us, but you've mentioned that isn't the structure you're trying to work with anymore.

Comment: It seems to me that the HTML hard coded is just to create the text box that will allow entry of the values. If that's the case then yes it can remain. What this script did is the following: Upon clicking the script in the Toolbar a text box would appear, we could then paste the values into the text box from Excel and upon clicking the "Enter Forecast Values" those values would be entered into their separate input fields. I'm trying to re-create this script for another page, that will basically allow us to enter values over multiple input fields. How can I show the HTML code of the page?

Comment: You can paste it here from the relevant section of the source code of the target page. Your browser's developer tools can help you find it, using the element inspector